# Howto custom ASP.NET Core configuration file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Migrating from from old ASP.NET MVC 4.5 to ASP.NET Core. Previously had some custom settings in web.config -- what to do now?

Came across a [guide](https://adrientorris.github.io/aspnet-core/add-custom-configuration-file-using-options-and-configuration-objects.html) which basically tells you to edit Startup.cs and add a few lines here an there:

In the ctr:

```
.AddJsonFile($"customSettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
```

In ConfigureServices(...):

```
services.Configure<CustomSection1>(options => Configuration.GetSection("CustomSection1").Bind(options));
services.Configure<CustomSection2>(options => Configuration.GetSection("CustomSection2").Bind(options));
```

Now, I'm a [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) kind of guy, so what's preventing me from simply:

```
public static T Settings = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("custom.json"));
```

The former examples are good for injection. Anything other than that?

Comment: Mostly `optional: true, reloadOnChange: true`, which you obviously cannot do with a `ReadAllText` call. Besides that doesn't use the IoC container

Comment: Reading configuration file in startup.cs is the best option rather than reading file and deserialize it. You can use those configurations anywhere in the system using DI. You can access configuration using  **IConfiguration**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1